# Compiling and using OpenSSL for Android, on windows using eclipse

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, openssl

I am developing an Android app on windows, using eclipse.
I would like to use OpenSSL for my Android application. It needs to be used with C++ via NDK.
I tried to download fries' OpenSSL source code from https://github.com/fries/android-external-openssl and build it.
I read the README.android file, but I didn't understand what these instructions are for.
Do I need to download the OpenSSL source code in addition to the fries source code?
I have tried putting all the files from Fries' into my jni folder of the Android project. It complained about not finding e_os.h and openssl/crypto.h and others like that.
More specifically:

```
In file included from D:/Projects/Fatal/Android/OpenSSL/jni/ssl/s2_meth.c:59:
D:/Projects/Fatal/Android/OpenSSL/jni/ssl/ssl_locl.h:124:18: error: e_os.h: No such file or directory
D:/Projects/Fatal/Android/OpenSSL/jni/ssl/ssl_locl.h:126:28: error: openssl/buffer.h: No such file or directory
D:/Projects/Fatal/Android/OpenSSL/jni/ssl/ssl_locl.h:127:26: error: openssl/comp.h: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure why it doesn't find those files, I tried to add all sort of paths into LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in all sort of Android.mk files, but nothing worked.

I would like to know how to build OpenSSL for Android. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the fries' github is just something to patch the source of OpenSSL, it's not a stand alone OpenSSL for android.
It is required because it provide Android.mk files which are required by ndk-build of ndk. You don't want to build it using standard gcc because you want to build it for Android.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I kept coming across this when I was searching for this problem. In the case that you *are* building a standalone OpenSSL to go with your project and are getting this error, I found a solution as per [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/DMftXJOCHsQ):

In `openssl-android/crypto`, `openssl-android/ssl`, and `openssl-android/apps`, you'll find a variable declaration for `local_c_includes` that is something like this:

```
local_c_includes := \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH) \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/crypto/asn1 \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/crypto/evp \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/include \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/include/openssl
```

If you've placed your `openssl-android` directory in your Android project in the `project/jni` directory, then these variables no longer point to the correct location. The way I solved it was to modify these paths to be relative to `LOCAL_PATH`:

```
local_c_includes := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/.. \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/asn1 \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/evp \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/openssl
```

Remember, you'll have to do this for each of the directories you're trying to build (`crypto`, `ssl`, or `apps`).