# Open Ssl NDK build issue

Tags: build, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface, gnu-make

G:/Ndk_r9d

G:/Openssl-1.0.1i - downloaded from openssl.rg

In openssl **apps,crypto** and **ssl** i have added android.mk file.

1. [apps android.mk](http://pastebin.com/Yp67MRZn)
2. [crypto android.mk](http://pastebin.com/KHGET9gp)
3. [ssl android.mk](http://pastebin.com/nyqxHwv8)

And i copied these Android.mk files from [here](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android).

G:/Openssl-1.0.1i>ndk-build

Each and every time i am getting different issue i.e make.exe ***Access is denied and
No such file or directory.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500246/compiling-and-using-openssl-for-android-on-windows-using-eclipse) solution also but no luck.

I have opened cmd prompt "Run As Administrator".

Is there anyother way to get **libcrypto.so** and **libssl.so**?

**Problem solved by disabilng antivirus.**

Comment: Have you considered using the instructions provided by OpenSSL at their [Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) wiki page? Or considered a prebuilt OpenSSL library for Android, like [Noloader Github](http://github.com/noloader?tab=repositories)?